# Showing distance measurement of images

Tags: android, image, button, textfield, pixel

I have 2 images, and a button that moves the images closer.  Now i need to get a textfield to show the distance between both of the images in pixels.  So the label can show that the images are 20 pixels away from each other, or if i move the images closer the textfield will show 19 pixels.

Here is my code now

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) red.getLayoutParams()).topMargin += 1;
                red.requestLayout();
                ((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) blue.getLayoutParams()).topMargin -= 1.5;
                blue.requestLayout();
                text2.setText("" + (int) red.getCameraDistance());
```

The 'text2.setText("" =...."  line of code, was my attempt trying to figure out the distance between the 2 images. But it didn't work...

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Make a stab at it and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

xml:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/image1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
.../>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/image2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
.../>

<EditText
android:id="@+id/distance"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
.../>
```

Activity:

```
 EditText textDistance = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.distance);
 ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
 ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);

 float distance = image2.getX()- image1.getX()+image1.getWidth();

 textDistance.setText((String.valueOf(distance));
```

Comment: i get a error when i add 'int distance = image2.getX"... The errors say "Requires int  but found float"

Comment: My bad, should be  float distance = image2.getX()- image1.getX()+image1.getWidth(); then :)

Comment: after i change 'int' into float.   text2.setText(distance); gets an error.  The error says ' can not resolve method setText(float)"

Comment: Then android studio prompts me with a solution, use this code ' text2.setText((int) distance);' then the error goes away, but when i try to click on a button the app crashes.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for forgetting about cast, it's pretty late :P Can you show me what log you get when app crashes?

Comment: 11-13 16:25:18.869    3754-3754/? E/memtrack﹕ Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-13 16:25:18.870    3754-3754/? E/android.os.Debug﹕ failed to load memtrack module: -2

Comment: 11-13 16:25:18.888    3754-3762/? E/art﹕ Thread attaching while runtime is shutting down: Binder_1

Comment: Try using textDistance.setText(String.valueOf(distance)); instead of casting to (int)